# How to interpret a val in Scala that is of type Option[T]

Tags: scala

I am trying to analyze Scala code written by someone else, and in doing so, I would like to be able to write Unit Tests (that were not written before the code was written, unfortunately).
Being a relative Newbie to Scala, especially in the Futures concept area, I am trying to understand the following line of code.

```
val niceAnalysis:Option[(niceReport) => Future[niceReport]] = None
```

**Update:** 
   The above line of code should be:

```
val niceAnalysis:Option[(NiceReport) => Future[NiceReport]] = None
```

- **Where NiceReport is a case class**

-----------Update ends here---------------- 
Since I am trying to mock up an Actor, I created this new Actor where I introduce my **niceAnalysis val** as a field. 
The first problem I see with this "niceAnalysis" thing is that it looks like an anonymous function. 
How do I "initialize" this val, or to give it an initial value. 

My goal is to create a test in my test class, where I am going to pass in this initialized val value into my test actor's receive method.

My naive approach to accomplish this looked like:

```
val myActorUnderTestRef = TestActorRef(new MyActorUnderTest("None))
```

Neither does IntelliJ like it. My SBT compile and test fails.

So, I need to understand the "niceAnalyis" declaration first and then understand how to give it an initial value. Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that this is a value that might contain a function from type `niceReport` to `Future[niceReport]`. You can pass an anonymous function or just a function pointer. The easiest to understand might be the pointer, so I will provide that first, but the easiest in longer terms would be the anonymous function most likely, which I will show second:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def strToFuture(x: String) = Future{ x } //merely wrap the string in a future
val foo = Option(strToFuture)
```

Conversely, the one liner is as follows:

```
val foo = Option((x:String)=>Future{x})
```

Comment: This makes sense. I am going to try this one now

Comment: I posted an update to my question because I just realized that I forgot to mention on other detail.

Comment: That doesn't change my answer. I used String, but you can use any type, including NiceReport.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Very timely. Crisp explanation.